# How do I display html within chrome's noscript tag?

Tags: html, google-chrome, noscript

When I view `noscript` in Chrome I'm seeing raw html displayed when JavaScript is turned off.

This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <div>No Javscript</div>
</noscript>
</body>
```

Will display:

```
<div>No Javscript</div>
```

This used to work, so I'm guessing there was a regression, but I can't find anything about it on the web.  In other browsers(safari, firefox), I don't see the HTML.  I'm using Chrome 26.0.1410.43 on OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Could the extra space in `</no script>` be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: Now that we know it's a typo, I've updated your question (so other people aren't confused).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Refreshing the page twice fixes this issue.

And it only appears when you first switch to disabling javascript (i.e. someone who browses with javascript disabled would not experience it)

Comment: Why page has to be refreshed twice in chrome only and not in any other browsers?

Comment: Is this a bug in Chrome? Doesn't sound like a feature to me.

Comment: @Jeff, it has been reported as a bug many times, including [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232410)

Comment: I don't think this is a solution.

Comment: There is still no solution I have found so far, although the bug has been reported already back in 2013 and the issue still persists. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=235158

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I spoke too soon.  Turning off AdBlock is the answer.

Comment: I was having this problem also and found that refreshing the page twice fixed it (I think turning AdBlock off refreshes the page also, which may be why this fixed it for you)

Comment: I can confirm that disabling adblock does not solve the problem. I tried disabling adblock, then disabled javascript, then reloaded the page once. HTML was not rendered properly in the noscript tag. Reloaded a second time, and HTML was rendered correctly from then on.