# html in noscript tag is not read until page reload

Tags: javascript, page-refresh, noscript

I have a noscript tag on one of my pages with a p and an a element inside of it. It is hidden when javascript is enabled and shows up when disabled, except that it shows up with the markup written out uninterpreted. If I refresh the browser the code is then interpreted and the link functions.

I'm hoping to be able to offer a link to a version of the page which works without javascript, so i'd like to be able to solve this. Is there a way to have the elements interpreted on the initial page load, without the user needing to refresh?

Comment: Did you disable JS **after** loading the page?

Comment: no - if i disable js with the page open nothing happens - then  if i refresh once i get the uninterpreted html, and if i refresh a second time i get the proper result. If i disable js without the page open then navigate to it the result is the same - uninterpreted, refresh, interpreted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800526/how-do-i-display-html-within-chromes-noscript-tag - i.e. turn off Adblock, only a problem when disabling js on the actual page. Flagged as duplicate

Comment: my apologies - i did search first but missed that question - thank you - solved the problem.